# Is it true that sup(A) ∈ A ⇔ A is finite?

Tags: real-analysis

Is it true that sup(A) ∈ A ⇔ A is finite?
The picture is my proof of one direction but I can't figure out the other direction.
[image: l]

Comment: No. Consider $A=[0,1]$.

Comment: Consider $A = [0,1]$ with the usual ordering.

Comment: What you've shown is that if the supremum is not in the set, the set is infinite. This is true in general. Similar holds for the infimum.

Comment: Thank you guys! It's really my fault to miss such a counter example.

Answer (score 2):

If $A$ is finite, then it is true that $\sup A\in A$. (Exercise!)

One does not need to prove this by contradiction. Simply notice that

- $\max A$ is the least upper bound for $A$ and
- $\max A\in A$.

However, the converse is not true (as mentioned in [my comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3412436/is-it-true-that-supa-%e2%88%88-a-%e2%87%94-a-is-finite/3412437#comment7018102_3412436)): consider $A=[0,1]$.

Answer (score 1):

If the supremum is in the set then it is simply the maximum. A set with a maximum need not be finite. Consider $[0,1]$. The maximum is 1 and $[0,1]$ is an uncountable set, so it cannot be finite.